Rear backup configuration
Want to backup my datavg volume group to NAS drive using Redhat "Relax and Recover (ReaR)" tool. I need some help with the configuration file
#lsblk
sdb   8:16   0  100G  0 disk 
├─datavg-worktest2lg 253:5    0   10G  0 lvm  /root/work/test2 
└─datavg-test        253:6    0   10G  0 lvm  /work/test

When I explicitly mention the below line it backup all the files from “/root/work/test2”
Not from “/work/test”. How can I backup all the files from Datavg volume group at once.Is there any other parameter kindly suggest
BACKUP_PROG_INCLUDE=( '/root/work/test2' )

/etc/rear/local.conf
OUTPUT=ISO
OUTPUT_URL=nfs://mynasdrive/tmp/backup_dest
OUTPUT_PREFIX="$HOSTNAME.`date +%m%d%y`"
BACKUP=NETFS
BACKUP_URL=nfs://mynasdrive/tmp/backup_dest
NETFS_PREFIX="$HOSTNAME.`date +%m%d%y`"
ONLY_INCLUDE_VG=( "datavg" )
BACKUP_PROG_INCLUDE=( '/root/work/test2' )
BACKUP_OPTIONS="nfsvers=3,nolock"
OUTPUT_OPTIONS="nfsvers=3,nolock"
NETFS_KEEP_OLD_BACKUP_COPY=y


"rear" being an English word is really terrible to search for; "rear backup tool" gives me links to military tactical stuff. Can you please link to "Rear"?

Hey @MarcusMüller sorry for the abbreviation.. it’s accutually Relax and recover..pls find some kb here Relax-and-Recover (ReaR) https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-relax-and-recover_rear

I went ahead and added that to your question :)

Is it more complicated than including that second path in the BACKUP_PROG_INCLUDE array? Or even to just empty the array (and rely on ONLY_INCLUDE_VG limiting the backup instead)?

@Kusalananda I tried only with ONLY_INCLUDE_VG option . It backups only metadata.. so I made an array for all the Filesystem and pass to BACKUP_PROG_INCLUDE

@MarcusMüller thank you

@user984993 if Kusalananda's comment helped you solve the issue, consider posting an answer to your own question – if you post an answer to a question post, you can accept that, so the question gets marked as solved, and people can in the future easily find the solution. Use the answer field below!
